# Ido: restrict to directories

Tags: emacs, ido

The command `ido-find-file` offers the option to restrict the completion list using a filter. For example, one may input `.cpp`, press `C-SPC` *et voila*, the completion list is restricted to files with `.cpp`.

However, sometimes it is useful to restrict the list to directories in the first steps of navigation, e.g. when one is navigating to a file, residing in a subdirectory of unknown name, which is located within a directory with a lot of ordinary files.

Is there some built-in functionality for restricting `ido` to accept only directories in the current step (current step is either delimited by a) calling an *un-restrict function*, or b) [also the better solution] by an actual naviagtional command, i.e. descending/ascending in the directory tree level)? Or, if not, can someone write a function to do just that?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is already present in form of `ido-dired`.

### UPD:

Two-stage `find-file` is as easy as you could imagine:

```
(defun find-file-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (ido-dired)
  (ido-find-file))
```

Comment: Can you change from `ido-dired` to normal `ido` (the other way, i.e. `ido-find-file` -> `ido-dired`: just press `C-x d`, works)? Otherwise this does not match the requirement.

Comment: You update does not work as expected either: after selecting a directory with `ido-dired`, a dired buffer is opened.

Comment: How is that a problem? You get to select the file you want in the directory you want. Dired buffer is a visual assistance bonus.

Comment: But I don't want that dired buffer. If you read my question, you will find that I want to filter the prompt in order to be able to first navigate the directory structure and then open the target file. [Maybe even reiterate that procedure in a different folder] I don't want to open any dired buffers (even if I can close them easily afterwards).